# uuidgen alternative

Tags: uuid

I'm running Windows XP. I don't have Microsoft Visual Studio installed and I don't want to install it.

I need a couple of UUIDs but `uuidgen` doesn't seem to be on my system.

Is there a single executable out there from a reputable source, that I can download and use to generate UUIDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aha, I already have python on my machine:

```
C:\WINDOWS>python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48::26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "licen
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('640628d4-4e4d-4a7a-8f9e-24aa6106b56a')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a web service rather than a local binary, you could try my uuid-serve application. It's a Sinatra app [hosted on Heroku](http://uuid-serve.herokuapp.com/), and the source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/CodeGnome/uuid-serve).

Since it's a web application, there's nothing to install. There's even a RESTful URL for generating bulk UUIDs over SSL. For example:

```
curl -sL https://uuid-serve.herokuapp.com/bulk/5
```